# Flexbox - How to align items in navbar

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am having trouble aligning two items together in my navbar. I am trying to bring logo on left and align tabs on right.

I have created lis for links and simple h1 for logos. 
The trouble I am having is that h1 is taking all of space and pushing lis down to next line, I have tried doing several things but can't really figure it out where I am going wrong.

```css
body {
  margin: auto
}


/*navbar*/

.main-nav {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  float: right;
}

li {
  padding: 20px;
}

a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>My site</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav class="navbar">
      <h1>My Site</h1>
      <ul class="main-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use floats when working with Flexbox. Flexbox takes care of aligning your items the way you want. If you want two columns on the same row, add `display:flex` on the parent. If you want one on the left and one on the right,  use `justify-content: space-between`;

```css
body {
  margin: auto
}


/*navbar*/

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.main-nav {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 0.7em;     
}

li {
  padding: 20px;
}

a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>My site</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav class="navbar">
      <h1>My Site</h1>
      <ul class="main-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

In order to understand Flexbox, there is a [game](http://flexboxfroggy.com/) that will teach you all the necessary properties in an easy way. This visual [guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) will also help you.

Answer (score 1):

@Hanan: no need of using float just need to ad add `display: flex` and `justify-content: space-between`in navbar

```css
body {
 margin: auto
}

/*navbar*/

.main-nav {
 display: flex;
 list-style: none;
 font-size: 0.7em;
/*  float: right; */remove
}
.navbar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

li {
 padding: 20px;
}

a {
 color: black;
 text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>My site</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <nav class="navbar">
   <h1>My Site</h1>
   <ul class="main-nav">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
 </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Helful Answer.. Great.

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox is the easiest way. For the h1 set `flex: 1 auto`. This will make it grow to fill the remaining space. All navigation links will just consume the needed space. It's also working when wrapping the links into another element like `ul/li`

```css
.navbar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar h1 {
  flex: 1 auto;
}

.navbar a {
  padding: 0 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <h1>My Site</h1>
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    <a href="#">Link 4</a>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

please try to change your code to bellow.

```
body {
    margin: auto
}

/*navbar*/
.navbar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.main-nav {
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 0.7em;
}

li {
    padding: 20px;
    float: left;
}

a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```